# What is the best architecture to delete the video after app is uninstalled?

Tags: android, mobile-phone

I am trying to make an app for my online educational platform. I want offline download feature in the app. But at the same time, I want all the videos to be deleted once the app is uninstalled. What is the best architecture, I should follow?

Comment: What do you mean by "architecture"?

Comment: With Architecture I mean, how should I design my application to obtain the desired result in the best possible way. I know that I can encrypt my video and then only decrypt it using the app, but I am sure there is another best way. Something like what Netflix does.

Comment: Please [edit] and add that information and some more to your question, instead of comments.